# Can't destructure an object inside a function generator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I want to destructure the result of a previous yield using default values when the object is empty. But I'm getting a **Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined**, meaning that where I try to destructure the variable `theObject` is undefined, but why?

```js
const DEFAULT_POSITION = {x: 20, y: 20}
const myObject = {}

function* myGenerator(i) {
  const theObject = yield myObject;
  const { posX = DEFAULT_POSITION.x, posY = DEFAULT_POSITION.y, scale = 1 } = theObject

  yield {posX, posY, scale}
}
```

The first yield returns me an empty object as expected, but then when I run the generator again I get the error that the first item (`posX`) in the object destruction can not be read since the `theObject` is undefined.

Comment: How are you running the generator? Please post the complete code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you `yield myObject` *to the caller*, the result of that `yield` is read *from the caller* via `next(/* this "undefined" argument gets passed into your generator function*/)` call. So `theObject` is `undefined` because you're not using the generator as intended.

> When the iterator's next() method is called, the generator function's body is executed until the first yield expression, which specifies the value to be returned from the iterator
>
> Calling the next() method with an argument will resume the generator function execution, replacing the yield expression where execution was paused with the argument from next()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

It's not very intuitive, generator functions are weird like that.

The following works but is probably not what you want as far as I understand

```js
const DEFAULT_POSITION = {x: 20, y: 20}
const myObject = {}

function* myGenerator(i) {
  const theObject = yield
  const { posX = DEFAULT_POSITION.x, posY = DEFAULT_POSITION.y, scale = 1 } = theObject

  yield {posX, posY, scale}
}
const it = myGenerator()
console.log(it.next()) // -> {value: undefined, done: false}
console.log(it.next(myObject)) // -> {value: { posX: 20, posY: 20, scale: 1 }, done: false}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet thingy :-)

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation. I was reviewing a redux-saga work in a code review, but before I made a suggestion using destructuring there I just wanted to test this in isolation on the chrome console and ran into the problem I described. I'm going to wait and see how it goes in the review and come back to this question soon.

Answer (score 1):

## Understanding the Generator

One way of thinking of `yield` is as a breakpoint, which returns a value to the calling body.  It can also pass a value in the generator body, but the value needs to be passed in using `next()` as described in [MDN: Generator#next](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next):

> in `variable = yield expression`, the value passed to the `.next()` function will be assigned to variable.

In your case, there is no value passed to `next()` (at least not in your given code), so `theObject` is `undefined` and encountering an error when used in the restructuring assignment.

I've attempted to rework your code in two examples, w/ and w/o an argument passed to it for initialization and then some looping to demonstrate using a previous value.

---

#### No Arguments Passed to Generator

The following passes no arguments to the generator function.  The multiple yields are intended to demonstrate the returned value from the Generator.

```js
function* GetPositions(args={}) {
  const defaults = {x:20,y:20}
  const position = Object.assign({}, defaults, args)
  yield position             // return initial setup
  
  const { x:posX, y:posY, scale = 1 } = position
  yield {posX, posY, scale}  // return next value
}


let coord = GetPositions()
console.log( coord.next().value )  // {x:20, y:20}
console.log( coord.next().value )  // {posX:20, posY:20, scale:1}
```

---

#### Passing Arguments to Generator

The following passes one object to the generator function.  It is only a partial object as it contains one key to demonstrate using internal defaults.

```js
function* GetPositions(args={}) {
  const defaults = {x:20,y:20}
  const position = Object.assign({}, defaults, args)
  yield position             // return initial setup
  
  const { x:posX, y:posY, scale = 1 } = position
  yield {posX, posY, scale}  // return next value
}

let coord = GetPositions({x:1})   // initial argument
console.log( coord.next().value ) // {x:1, y:20}
console.log( coord.next().value ) // {posX:1, posY:20, scale:1}
```

---

### Looping in Generator

This would be closer to what you might use a generator for, since it is more common to use a generator in a repeated fashion, to generate sequences or advance values.

```js
function* GetPositions(args={}) {
  const defaults = {x:20,y:20}
  const position = Object.assign({}, defaults, args)
  let { x:posX, y:posY, scale = 1 } = position
  
  yield {posX, posY, scale}
  
  while(true){
    posX+=5, posY+=5
    yield {posX, posY, scale}     // return next value
  }
}

let coord = GetPositions({x:1})   // initial argument

console.log( coord.next().value ) // {posX:1,  posY:20, scale:1}
console.log( coord.next().value ) // {posX:6,  posY:25, scale:1}
console.log( coord.next().value ) // {posX:11, posY:30, scale:1}
```